# SharePoint List like Data Access Interface

Tags: sharepoint, orm, data-access-layer

I am impressed by the way we programmatically access lists in SharePoint. I percieve it as a Data Access Layer, while modeling the database is as simple as defining the columns in the List.

I am looking for a tool OR an application that would give me similar interface to a database. Basically, for some reason I cannot use SharePoint and I don't wish to take up the responsibility of modeling, deploying and maintaining the database. I find the SharePoint way of persistence management acceptable and exciting.

Can anyone suggest me something even close to this.

BTW, my application is on ASP.Net and my preferred RDBMS is MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the overhead and expense of a Sharepoint installation, 90% of the time all you really need is WSS 3.0 (free with a windows server license).

Comment: Chris ... thanx for responding. BTW, due to some challenges, SharePoint (or even WSS 3.0) is out of question for me, although I know that WSS is free.

Answer (score 0):

For auto generated entity classes you can use Linq To Sharepoint (SPMetal)

For hand written POCO entities you can try using [SharepointCommon](http://sharepointcommon.codeplex.com/) ORM

Comment: Please dont' duplicate your answers across posts. If the questions are different, tailor your answer to each question. If the questions are the same, then please flag one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use NOSQL database like MongoDb or CouchDB which are schema less, allowing you to freely add fields to JSON documents without having to first define schema.